# Making Jenkins plot plugin to work

Tags: jenkins, plot, jenkins-plugins

Ok, so as I understand, [Plot Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) is the only plugin for Jenkins that can generate plots from build's xml report.

First it wasn't available in plugins management section, so I had to upload it manually, and now I don't have "Plot build data" option in "Add post-build action" menu.

Should I use some other plugin, or this one just has to be configured in a strange way that I don't know about?

Jenkins version: 1.520, plugin version: 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding not being able to infall it from plugins menu - no idea.

"Plot build data" option in "Add post-build action" menu was not appearing because plot plugin is not working with matrix jobs.

There is an issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1397 and a fix https://github.com/jenkinsci/plot-plugin/pull/6 but Jenkins team is too lazy to integrate it

Comment: It seems that the latest version of the plot plugin supports matrix jobs. See the ChangeLog at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

From my Jenkins installation the Plot plugin (version 1.5) is visible and available for downloading into plugin configuration section. I'm using 1.530 Jenkins version.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to "Plot build data" option in "Add post-build action" I suspect this has to do with your Jenkins build/job type.

I have just done some experimentation and "Plot build data" doesn't appear for me in maven jobs. But it DOES appear when it is a "freestyle" build project.

Armed with my test information I had a look at the defects in this area for the Plot plugin.

And there are indeed defects for some other project types as follows:
 - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1397 (multi-configuration builds) 
 - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4790 (matrix builds) 
 - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8478 (maven2)

Comment: Yes and as I've commented on multi-configuration and builds there is a fix. But it's not getting integrated no idea why